# Better way to convert a file to .bib

Tags: python, csv, bibtex, bibliography

I have CSV Files, Text Files and Word Files that have tons of bibliography that I want to export to .bib file, preferably with a custom order defined by me.

What I want to know is, what's the best way to convert this information using Python, to a .bib file?

Is it converting Text to XML and maybe then to .bib? Or loading a CSV file and iterate through columns and write column by column?

I've worked a script for loading a CSV and take each column as a list, but to convert to .bib I can't solve how.

Here's the code I've pulled together:

```
import csv
import pandas
import bibtexparser
from bibtexparser.bparser import BibTexParser
from bibtexparser.customization import *


colnames = ['AUTHORS', 'TITLE', 'EDITOR']
data = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', names=colnames, delimiter =r";", encoding='latin1')

list1 = list(data.AUTHORS)



def customs(record):
    record = type(record)
    record = author(record)
    record = editor(record)
    return record

with open('123.bib','w') as bibtex_file:
    parser = BibTexParser()
    parser.customization = customs
```